# Custom Poste Type Woocommerce Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to make a Custom Post Type Woocommerce Product Page. But I haven't found a way to make this? Is it similar to making a standard Wordpress custom post type if yes what do I have to change? Very happy for any advice!
Best regards

Comment: I am not sure to understand, you want to customise the public page that shows product details ?

Comment: @Kaperto no I want to make a Plugin where I have a separate page to create a Woocommerce product, with limited options. But do I have to create this own custom page in the Admin Area make a new custom-post-type like normal Wordpress pages?

Comment: plugin code is for data handling and after you use theme to customise data display. edit your question to add more details about what you want to do and then we can help you more with advices to do that.